# When should I use du and de?

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot

Par exemple :

> - L'antibiotique est efficace sur un grand nombre de types de germes.
> - L'antibiotique est efficace sur un grand nombre du type du germe.

When should I use du and de and why?

Answer (score 1):

Not here, where *de* is ok both times.

In fact, *du* is a short form of *de le*. For example, I won't say *la vue de le port est belle*, I must say *la vue **du** port est belle*. I will however say *la vue de la mer est belle*.

Another error in your sentence is about *un grand nombre*, which implies “many”. Whatever it is many or few (but >1), you must use the plural form of the noun: *un grand nombre de types*. Every *type* itself is supposed to contain several somethings, so your sentence has to be *un grand nombre de types de germes*.

Sorry for my poor English. As a native French, I think that help people with my language is a way to improve my English. Hope I have been of some help to you.

Happy new year :^)

Answer (score 1):

Le mot « de » permet de lier deux choses en français.

Exemple :

> les chaussures de mon frère

Ici « de » lie « les chaussures » et « mon frère ».

« Du » en français est la contraction de « de » et « le » or en français on ne dit pas « de le ».

Exemple :

> les pommes **du** jardin

et pas :

> les pommes <strike>**de le**</strike> jardin

En terme général, on dit donc « du » quand on doit mettre un « de » devant l’article « le ».